# Often, Ubuntu 21.04 does not find the Wi-Fi driver

Tags: networking, drivers, xps

Recently, Ubuntu 21.04 began often not to find the Wi-Fi driver on upstart (lshw -c network gives an empty answer). I believe this behaviour was actually first seen with version 20.10. When I turn power off and then on again, the operating system often succeeds the second time. Sometimes more than one such turning off and on is required. Once I went into the BIOS and turned LAN first off and then on again. That made the operating system recognise the Wi-Fi driver for that session but not permanently. Does anyone here have a similar experience and know a remedy? The Laptop is Dell XPS 13 7390, and lshw -c network describes the hardware as follows.

```
*-network<br>
description: Wireless interface<br>
product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200<br>
vendor: Intel Corporation<br>
physical id: 0<br>
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0<br>
logical name: wlp2s0<br>
version: 1a<br>
serial: 3c:9c:0f:59:1f:8c<br>
width: 64 bits<br>
clock: 33MHz<br>
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless<br>
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=192.168.87.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes<br>
wireless=IEEE 802.11<br>
resources: irq:18 memory:9e200000-9e203fff
```

Comment: just install synaptic manager and searc for your driver and download it

Comment: Supplement: When the operating system has not found the Wi-Fi driver, it also typically halts at shut down so that I must do a hard break to turn of the laptop. The screen is just empty with a cursor in the upper left corner. After I have pressed the hard break button, the screen sometimes displays a few lines, apparently about failing contact to periferal units such as a mouse. This text diappears so quickly that there is not sufficient time to read all of it. I have not yet seen any useful proposal of a remedy.

Comment: Canonical seems to have fixed the bug in recent updates.

Comment: No! Just after the above was written, the WiFi-driver was again missing after the laptop was turned on. It then cropped up after shutdown and a new start.

Comment: The problem did not arise after I upgraded to 21.10.